# How could I prove this equation true?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $H, K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$ with $K \subset N_H$. Show that
$$\#(HK) = \frac{\#(H)\#(K)}{\#(H \cap K)}$$

What would I need to do to prove this equation true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $K$ normal in $H$? I'm not following your meaning of $K \subset N_H$.

Comment: Hi I think it is is just that $K$ is some subset of $N_H$

Comment: But what is $N_H$?

Comment: Oh $N_H$ is the normal subgroup of H, $N_H = \{n | nh = hn; h \in H; n \in N\}$ I think that should be it

Comment: @rschwieb Oh yes I didn't realise that, I meant that since $HK = \{hk | h \in H; k \in K\}$, if $hk$ and $kh$ are classed as distinct elements for all $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ then $\#(HK) = \#(H)\#(K)$, but I'll change that in the description.

Comment: But the equation is true anyway, without any assumption about $K$ normalizing $H$.

Comment: Indeed, if I remember you can let $G$ act on the cosets and count that way too. The normality condition is apparently included to smooth the way for an argument like the one I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K\subseteq N_G(H)$, and of course $H\subseteq N_G(H)$, you have $HK\subseteq N_G(H)$, and so $H\lhd HK$.

Simply by counting items in cosets you always have that $|G/N||N|=|G|$ in finite groups, where $N\lhd G$. Rewritten this says $|G/N|=|G|/|N|$

In this case, the second isomorphism theorem says that

$$HK/H\cong K/(H\cap K)$$

Applying the first observation, $|HK|/|H|=|K|/|H\cap K|$.

Multiplying by $|H|$ on both sides, you have your equation.